# Rails / ActiveRecord equivalent of Underscore.js's .groupBy?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, underscore.js

My User model has a bunch of Songs.

I want to as a user for an associative array of all the songs, grouped by a property of each song (the name of the artist, song.artist_name), where the artists name is the key.

I feel like this basic clustering pattern should be covered by Ruby / Rails, but I can't find what it's called...

Comment: once you are in Ruby, the closest reference wouldn't underscore's groupBy but Enumerable#group_by

Comment: If you add this as an answer, you win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group

Example:

```
Song.find( /* Some stuff your want */ ).group( 'artist' )
```

Comment: But I don't want to SUM or otherwise take the aggregate of my songs, I actually want each song, but sorted into groups with similar artists...

Comment: The example uses SUM, but also `.group()`, this is where your magic comes. Let me edit my answer with an example.

Comment: Would work if I wasn't on Heroku / Postgres, which I didn't mention in the question. Accepting for others' reference.